# How to apply Word to vector algorithm with Naive or Svm intead of tf-idf and count vectorizor?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, word2vec, supervised-learning

I am trying to implement word to vector with Supervised learning to predict sentiment of any document or News article. word2vec represents each words corresponding to real numbers and create vector based on occurance of that word in the document.

My data Preprocessing is as follows:

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer=to_lemmas)),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB())])
tuned_parameters = {
    'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)],
    'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__alpha': [1, 1e-1, 1e-2]
}

score = 'f1_macro'

clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf, tuned_parameters, cv=10, scoring=score)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Here I'm applying countvectorizor which gives word count, it is passed to tf-idf which gives word frequency and then as classifier Multinomial naive Bays is Applied.

Grid searchCV is used to tune best out model for classification

then clf.fit is used to train the model and clf.predict is used to predict sentiment of sentence passed.

My this model gives me classification report like this:

```
 irrelevant     0.9739    0.7517    0.8485       149
    negative     0.6308    0.5430    0.5836       151
     neutral     0.7082    0.8687    0.7803       419
    positive     0.5797    0.3670    0.4494       109
```

I want to apply Word to vector embedding here, Please suggest how i can implement word to vector embedding with Naive and SVM.

https://github.com/akanshajainn/Sentiment-Analysis-Twitter-word2vec-keras

https://www.bonaccorso.eu/2017/08/07/twitter-sentiment-analysis-with-gensim-word2vec-and-keras-convolutional-networks/

Comment: Do you really want to "implement" word2vec from scratch – as opposed to either (1) reusing word-vectors from elsewhere as a possible aid to your classifier; or (2) training your own word-vectors using an existing working library?